# Comandos ESC/POS

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, bluetooth, impresión

Buenas si alguien me puede ayudar Estaria muy agradecido.

Tengo una App hecha en Xamarin.Android y C# y esta terminada ya el problema que tengo es para la impresion.

Por ejemplo necesito saber como crear comandos ESC/POS para enviarlo a una Impresora Bluetooth pero no tengo la minima idea de como empezar a crear los comandos para la impresion.

si alguien porfavor me puede ayudar.

Comment: Hola Jose. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Si seria un buen paso es que no se ni como empezar a crear este tipo de comandos.

Comment: Has de investigar y tratar algo. Si no, como tienes +20 rep, puedes entrar en el [chat] para pedir orientacion. Aqui ayudamos con errores concretos, pero empezar has de hacerlo tu. Un saludo